# Redirect URL path to forward to tomcat servlet using Apache/mod_proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

I currently have a tomcat servlet 1 running under the ROOT:

api1.myhost.com:8080/

I'm using mod_proxy and simply forwarding all requests from
api1.myhost.com to this instance. This is working as of today.

I now have installed a second servlet 2 which runs under the same instance of tomcat (same IP address):

www.myhost.com:8080/servlet2

I want all requests to a new URL api2 to go to that second servlet such that:

**api2**.myhost.com

now gets forwarded to the second servlet instance.

I've created an A record such that api2.myhost.com points to my server IP. How do you make api2.myhost.com forward to www.myhost.com:8080/servlet2  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make two VirtualHost's with on pointing to the first webapp, the other to the second.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api1.myhost.com
    ProxyPass / http://api1.myhost.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://api1.myhost.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api2.myhost.com
        ProxyPass / http://www.myhost.com:8080/servlet2
        ProxyPassReverse / http://www.myhost.com:8080/servlet2
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that since the path will be different on tomcat than on apache, you will need to use relative URLs in your application.

Comment: awesome this worked with one minor correction. I had to have the following line also: 

NameVirtualHost *:80

Comment: what file do we add these virtualhost records to?

Comment: Any file that is included in the main apache conf file. There is often a separate file for each virtual host.